# Setting source of chart data series from other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem concerning setting the data series from other worksheets. 
Here's my code:

```
Charts("chart1").SeriesCollection.Add _ 
    source:=Workbooks("Excel1.xls").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:a19")
```

Error: Subscript out of range.

I think something is wrong on how I refer on the workbook. I tried `Application.Workbooks`... Same result. How should I refer to the other other workbook?

Comment: Does the chart named "chart1" exist? Does the workbook named "Excel1.xls" exist and **open**? Does the workbook have "sheet1"?

Comment: actually my Chart is c0(3).Chart.SeriesCollection, "Excel1.xls" exist in the same folder with the activeworkbook and the data is stored at "sheet1"

Comment: I tried using only the same workbook, I can only refer upto 7 worksheets. Can I extend the number of worksheets as my source? If yes how? I refere to more than 7 worksheets and I get the same error. Error: Subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just made error in naming my worksheets. Instead of "Sheet1", I accidentally named one of my sheets "Sheet1 " which caused the error. That is all.